# IDA PRO Imports Names Lost in a accident, Reanalyze does nothing. How to make unexplored imports?

Tags: ida

I have put alot of work into renaming and fixing lvar types to better understand the code I made a mistake when I was converting some `unk_dword` to array I missed that it wasn't set to db but rather dd and it overwritten lots of stuff I lost many my own stuff which I know I won't get back but I can live with that, but I can't seem to get the imports to evaluate with the proper names like they were before.

I tried `Load->FLIRT signature file` with `Microsoft VisualC 2-10/net runtime` which seems to be right, didn't do anything.

In output Window I'm getting

`004DB200: Already data or code (hint: make 'unexplored')`

I guess I need to make it unexplored? how would I do that? I tried Undefining the Imports with the `U Key` it doesn't work.

Here is some screenshots how it looks

Before looked like this 

[image: before imports]

After looks like this

[image: after imports]

How it really looks like

[image: imports declares]

Here is how the bytes used to look like and how they look now (8 extra bytes)

[image: import bytes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This fix doesn't save to database or is overwritten upon loading IDB database it always reverts back to messed up! (I think there is something I missed to change)**

Not the right way to do it.. but I managed to solve this using `IDC Scripts`

Open a fresh IDA PRO let it analyze then go to `File -> Produce File -> Dump Database to IDC File.`

Open dumped `idc` file in notepad and search for the start of Imports comments such as `; Imports from GDI32.dll` since thats where the first Import starts.

Now just copy+paste from the `idc` file all the way to the end of the function before the bracket.

Backup your messed up `project.idb` file because this may mess up it even more if you are not careful!.

Now go to `File->IDC Command...` and paste something I posted at the end of this post.

**IDC Command Text box has limitations you can't paste too much so you need to split up by blocks, I advise make sure your block starts with `MakeDword` don't end with that.**

Here was my first Imports from `idc` file what it generated below.
`(This will only work for my application only obviously, just showing you what you need to look for.)`

```
auto x;
#define id x
MakeArray   (0X4DA0EC,  0XF14);
ExtLinA     (0X4DB200,  0,  "; ");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB200,  1,  "; Imports from GDI32.dll");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB200,  2,  "; ");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB200,  3,  "; Section 4. (virtual address 000DB000)");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB200,  4,  "; Virtual size                  : 0000090E (   2318.)");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB200,  5,  "; Section size in file          : 00000A00 (   2560.)");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB200,  6,  "; Offset to raw data for section: 0002FC00");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB200,  7,  "; Flags C0000040: Data Readable Writable");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB200,  8,  "; Alignment     : default");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB200);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB200,  "GetObjectA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB204);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB204,  "DeleteObject");
MakeByte    (0X4DB208);
MakeArray   (0X4DB208,  0X4);
ExtLinA     (0X4DB20C,  0,  "; ");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB20C,  1,  "; Imports from KERNEL32.dll");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB20C,  2,  "; ");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB20C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB20C,  "GetModuleFileNameA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB210);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB210,  "WritePrivateProfileStringA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB214);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB214,  "GetTickCount");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB218);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB218,  "CloseHandle");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB21C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB21C,  "GetFileTime");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB220);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB220,  "CreateFileA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB224);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB224,  "GetPrivateProfileIntA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB228);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB228,  "GetPrivateProfileStringA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB22C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB22C,  "VirtualAlloc");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB230);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB230,  "VirtualFree");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB234);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB234,  "TerminateProcess");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB238);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB238,  "GetExitCodeProcess");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB23C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB23C,  "CreateProcessA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB240);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB240,  "GetCommandLineA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB244);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB244,  "SetConsoleTitleA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB248);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB248,  "Sleep");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB24C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB24C,  "SetEndOfFile");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB250);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB250,  "SetStdHandle");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB254);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB254,  "GetFileType");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB258);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB258,  "ExitProcess");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB25C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB25C,  "GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB260);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB260,  "PeekConsoleInputA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB264);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB264,  "GetConsoleMode");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB268);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB268,  "SetConsoleMode");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB26C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB26C,  "ReadConsoleInputA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB270);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB270,  "SetEnvironmentVariableA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB274);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB274,  "CompareStringW");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB278);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB278,  "CompareStringA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB27C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB27C,  "LoadLibraryA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB280);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB280,  "WaitForSingleObject");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB284);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB284,  "GetStringTypeW");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB288);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB288,  "GetStringTypeA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB28C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB28C,  "IsBadCodePtr");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB290);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB290,  "IsBadWritePtr");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB294);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB294,  "IsBadReadPtr");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB298);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB298,  "GetOEMCP");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB29C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB29C,  "GetACP");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2A0);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2A0,  "GetCPInfo");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2A4);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2A4,  "GetEnvironmentStringsW");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2A8);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2A8,  "GetTimeZoneInformation");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2AC);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2AC,  "GetSystemTime");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2B0);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2B0,  "GetLocalTime");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2B4);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2B4,  "__imp_RtlUnwind");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2B8);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2B8,  "GetLastError");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2BC);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2BC,  "GetEnvironmentStrings");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2C0);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2C0,  "FreeEnvironmentStringsW");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2C4);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2C4,  "GetCurrentProcess");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2C8);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2C8,  "HeapAlloc");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2CC);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2CC,  "HeapReAlloc");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2D0);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2D0,  "HeapFree");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2D4);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2D4,  "RaiseException");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2D8);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2D8,  "GetVersion");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2DC);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2DC,  "ReadFile");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2E0);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2E0,  "WriteFile");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2E4);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2E4,  "SetFilePointer");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2E8);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2E8,  "HeapDestroy");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2EC);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2EC,  "LCMapStringW");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2F0);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2F0,  "SetHandleCount");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2F4);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2F4,  "GetStdHandle");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2F8);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2F8,  "GetStartupInfoA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB2FC);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB2FC,  "MultiByteToWideChar");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB300);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB300,  "WideCharToMultiByte");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB304);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB304,  "LCMapStringA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB308);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB308,  "UnhandledExceptionFilter");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB30C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB30C,  "FreeEnvironmentStringsA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB310);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB310,  "HeapCreate");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB314);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB314,  "SetUnhandledExceptionFilter");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB318);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB318,  "GetFileAttributesA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB31C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB31C,  "FlushFileBuffers");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB320);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB320,  "GetProcAddress");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB324);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB324,  "GetModuleHandleA");
MakeByte    (0X4DB328);
MakeArray   (0X4DB328,  0X4);
ExtLinA     (0X4DB32C,  0,  "; ");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB32C,  1,  "; Imports from USER32.dll");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB32C,  2,  "; ");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB32C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB32C,  "MessageBoxA");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB330);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB330,  "LoadImageA");
MakeByte    (0X4DB334);
MakeArray   (0X4DB334,  0X4);
ExtLinA     (0X4DB338,  0,  "; ");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB338,  1,  "; Imports from WSOCK32.dll");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB338,  2,  "; ");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB338);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB338,  "__imp_ioctlsocket");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB33C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB33C,  "__imp_inet_ntoa");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB340);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB340,  "__imp_WSACleanup");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB344);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB344,  "__imp_WSAStartup");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB348);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB348,  "__imp_recvfrom");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB34C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB34C,  "__imp_sendto");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB350);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB350,  "__imp_recv");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB354);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB354,  "__imp_closesocket");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB358);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB358,  "__imp_socket");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB35C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB35C,  "__imp_inet_addr");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB360);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB360,  "__imp_setsockopt");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB364);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB364,  "__imp_htons");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB368);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB368,  "__imp_htonl");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB36C);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB36C,  "__imp_bind");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB370);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB370,  "__imp_gethostbyname");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB374);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB374,  "__imp_connect");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB378);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB378,  "__imp_send");
MakeByte    (0X4DB37C);
MakeArray   (0X4DB37C,  0X4);
ExtLinA     (0X4DB380,  0,  "; ");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB380,  1,  "; Imports from zlib.dll");
ExtLinA     (0X4DB380,  2,  "; ");
MakeDword   (x=0X4DB380);
OpOff       (x, 0,  0);
OpOff       (x, 128,    0);
MakeName    (0X4DB380,  "__imp_compress");
MakeByte    (0X4DB384);
MakeArray   (0X4DB384,  0X4);
```